# DIfferent behavior on last iteration with php foreach

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

I have a basic php script that loops through a bunch of custom fields (in wordpress):

```
<?php foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
     {image: '<?php echo $image['url']; ?>', thumb: '<?php echo $image['sizes']['slideThumb']; ?>'},
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

As you can see, there is a comma at the end of the array. I would like to remove the comma on the last iteration. How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Work it the other way round, put a comma __before__ every entry except the first

Comment: It looks like you *might* be *trying* to write JSON; in which case, create an appropriately structured PHP array and `echo json_encode(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
 $i = 0;
 $numItems = count($images);
 foreach( $images as $image ): ?>
     {image: '<?php echo $image["url"]; ?>', 
       thumb: '<?php echo $image["sizes"]["slideThumb"]; ?>'}
     <?php if(++$i !== $numItems): ?>,<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: More than likely you can use foreach( $images as $i=>$image ) rather than initializing and incrementing a counter separately.

Comment: i dont get any. could be some typo ?

Comment: I didnt wrap the top two lines in php tags. Now that they are wrapped, I am receiving an error: <br />
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>path/here</b> on line <b>72</b><br />

Comment: is `$images` valid? also, `$numItems` defined?

Comment: I got it working. Image was not defined, I deleted it from my original code. Oops! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values you want to be comma separated into an array, and then use implode().

Or you can assign all that into a string, and use trim() to remove the last comma.

With both of those you will need to assign the end result into a variable (array or string) within the loop, then echo that one thing after the loop.